# How long does it usually take until package updates on CTAN can be downloaded via MiKTex console?

Tags: packages, miktex, ctan, update

I am using a package that has received an update on CTAN yesterday (3rd of June 2021). I wanted to download the most recent version of this package via MiKTeX console, but according to MiKTeX console, no update is available.
I am curious how long it usually takes for updates on CTAN to become available on the download mirrors that MiKTeX relies on. Should I expect hours, days, weeks or even longer time periods here?

Comment: Days. While TeX Live (usually) pulls updates from CTAN daily, MikTeX does slightly less regularly every few days up to possibly a week (the last updates were on 2021-06-03, 2021-05-29, 2021-05-20, 2021-05-18, but usually it won't be a lot more than a week between updates). MikTeX policy is that you can complain on the bugtracker if a package in MikTeX is one month behind CTAN.

Comment: Around  a week is normal, but a month or so is possible too, probably caused by holidays.

Comment: Yesterday was the 6th of june? Really? :o) There was an  update this morning, as you can check on MiKTeX.org

Comment: @Bernard oh, I certainly screwed that up :D where can I find the dates of the last updates on miktex.org? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: You can have a look at the package list (https://miktex.org/packages). One column shows when the package was last updated. This can be used as an approximation to find out when the last updates were uploaded.

Comment: You click on `Packages > Browse`, and you'll  see the list of last updated packages, with the date.

Comment: @moewe feel free to convert your comments into an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you will have to wait a few days.

While TeX Live (usually) pulls updates from CTAN daily, MikTeX does so slightly less regularly every few days (about 3 to 10 days). It is not unusual to have to wait for a week, but usually it does not take much longer than a week and a few days.

As a data point there were updates on 2021-06-03, 2021-05-29, 2021-05-20, 2021-05-18, 2021-05-09, 2021-05-08, 2021-04-27, 2021-04-23, 2021-04-14, 2021-04-07.

Once MikTeX has packaged the updates, it takes a while for all mirrors to pick up the changes, but there we are usually talking hours.

[MikTeX policy is that you can complain on the bugtracker if a package in MikTeX is one month behind CTAN.](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)